# fazer query com c# e xml

Tags: c#, xml

Ola,

Eu estou tentando fazer uma query em c# utilizando xml mas esta a dar-me um erro.

alguem podia ajudar-me?

codigo:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\..\WindowsFormsApp10\stores.xml");
        var xpath = "//store[Color='Pink']";
        var result = doc.XPathEvaluate(xpath);
        textBox1.Text = result.ToString();




    }
```

erro: surge isto na textbox: "System.Xml.XPath.XPathEvaluator+d__1`1[System.Object]"

xml:

```
<stores>
<store rollNumer="170">
    <Name>Jonh</Name>
        <Color>Pink</Color>
    <Sell>Sugar</Sell>
</store>

<store rollNumer="120">
    <Name>Tedy</Name>
        <Color>Brown</Color>
    <Sell>Rice</Sell>
</store>
```

Obrigado

Comment: sem colcoar o xml ai fica bem difícil de ajudar..

Comment: O que vc quer que apareça no textbox?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o seu problema? O que vc quer colocar no textbox?

Answer (score 2):

Pela [documentação do framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathevaluate?view=netframework-4.8), o método `XPathEvaluate` retorna um objeto que pode ser um `bool`, um `double`, uma `string` ou um `IEnumerable<T>`.

> An object that can contain a bool, a double, a string, or an IEnumerable.

Considerando que você pega o seu `result` e coloca em um `TextBox`, presumi-se que você está a espera de uma `string`. Sendo assim, você poderia fazer `var result = doc.XPathEvaluate(xpath) as string;`, mas sem conhecer o XML fica realmente difícil verificar se não há outro problema.

Código completo:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\cesar\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp10\WindowsFormsApp10\stores.xml");
    var xpath = "//store[Color='170']";
    var result = doc.XPathEvaluate(xpath) as string;
    textBox1.Text = result;
}
```

Comment: o xml esta assim `code` <stores>
 <store rollNumer="170">
     <Name>Jonh</Name>
            <Color>Pink</Color>
     <Sell>Sugar</Sell>
 </store>

 <store rollNumer="120">
     <Name>Tedy</Name>
            <Color>Brown</Color>
     <Sell>Rice</Sell>
 </store>

</stores>
 e tambem ja mudei o Color='Pink' mas ainda nao finciona  Obrigado